# Jquery select multiple nth-childs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I want to select all rows in a table but exclude some columns, it is also not possible to assign classnames in this case.

what i have now is this:

http://jsbin.com/ibulej/5/edit

which works for one column.

I will use that later for a inline-table search for different tables, where i have to exclude some columns.

whats the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: What is the criteria to exclude matches, what don't you want to match?

Comment: its for many different tables, so one time i want to exclude only colum 1, next table i want to exclude column 2,5,6, or only the last and the 2nd... best way for me is that i can define the excluded columns in a array lik ['1','5','6']...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to exclude columns from selection which uses a combination of `$.filter` and `$.index` to accomplish the task

```
 var cols = [2,3,4];


  $("#button").click(function() {
      var jo = $("#tableid tr").find('td').filter(function(i){
         if($.inArray($(this).index()+1,cols) != -1)
             return false;
          else 
              return true;
       });


    jo.css("background-color","red");


  });
```

Build your exclude list in `cols` array and those will be excluded from selection.

Reference: [$.index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)  [$.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/L7D9C/2/)

I am not sure if this is the best way, but it works for what you need.

Comment: Thanks! do you have a idea how i can use your solution here: http://jsbin.com/axogol/3/edit